# How to pass text from a single form field to two form fields

Tags: javascript, php, html, query-string

I have an opt-in form asking for `fullName`, `email` and `phonenumber`.
On the next page I have a calendar booking tool, to which I want to pass the data from the opt-in form. But the fields in this tool are `firstName`, `lastName`, `email` and `phonenumber`.

For specific reasons, I cannot split my opt-in to ask for `firstName` and `fullName`. If I could, I could just use query string e.g
`?firstName=Tom&lastName=Tim&email=tem@tom.ca&phonenumber=123`

So I basically need to know how I can split the input from `fullName` on my opt-in to `firstName` and `lastName` on my booking page.

Comment: you could split `fullName` based on white-space (`fullName.split(' ')`) but you are not granted the result. For example, if `fullName` is "John Dorian Doe" how would you determine whether the last name is just "Doe" or "Dorian Doe"?

Comment: how would I map that to the correct field in the second form? its not critical if a middle name gets recorded together with the last name - I just need both fields to be populated

Comment: You could write the data to and retrieve them from the local storage ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)); the form that contains the `fullName` field will write its value in the local storage, for example, `onSubmit` and the page with the two separated fields will read the value from the local storage, say `onLoad`, split it and use the chunks to set the value of `firstName` and `lastName`.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but the answer is you can not. There is no 100% safe way to split fullName into firstname lastname.

As in the comment from secan you could split by `fullName.split(' ')` or `preg_split("/ /",fullName)` but you have to let the user check if that is correct. You could use a firstname database or a country complete name database but people can change their names to whatever they want(well almost) and its not safe to assume you can cover all names.